# Segfault issue possibly involving scope

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have a header file containing `char** globalScreen`, which I have allocated memory inside of a function which is called as soon as the program starts in main.c.

I have allocated the memory the following way;

```
    char (*globalScreen)[SSIZEY] = malloc(SSIZEX * SSIZEY * sizeof(char*));

    int i,j;
    for(i = 0;i < SSIZEX;i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < SSIZEY;j++)
        {
            globalScreen[i][j] = (char)0x41;
        }
    }
```

And also initialised the array.

I can then successfully print the entire array, but only from inside the function that **I allocated and initialised it in. When I try to access the array from `main` - after calling my function which initialises the array - the program segfaults.**

I've tried debugging with lldb but discovered that it doesn't seem to be able to find any of the locations where I'm trying to set them.
The relevant part of the header file is as follows;

```
        #ifndef _VECTORDATA_H_
            #define _VECTORDATA_H_
        #include "vectorAPI.h"

        char** globalScreen;
        #endif
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts from the header file?

Comment: Can you also post the whole function that initializes the array?

Comment: rename char** globalScreen; to char** globalScreenXXX; and try to compile..I think that they are different variables one of them local and the other is global.

Comment: @houssam Ahah, you're perfectly correct, can't believe I didn't see that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your initialization function is something like this:

```
void initialize()
{
    char (*globalScreen)[SSIZEY] = malloc(SSIZEX * SSIZEY * sizeof(char*));
    // rest of code
}
```

Which means that it declares a new variable named `globalScreen`, instead of giving value to the global variable.

Additionally, you can't access `globalScreen` as a 2D array if it wasn't declared as one without a cast. Moreover, it's redundant to use a pointer-to-pointer `char **` instead of a single pointer `char *` if you only want a 2D array.

Try this code instead:

```
char * globalScreen;

void initialize()
{
    globalScreen = (char *) malloc(SSIZEX * SSIZEY * sizeof(char*));

    char (*tmp)[SSIZEY] = globalScreen;

    int i,j;
    for(i = 0;i < SSIZEX;i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < SSIZEY;j++)
        {
            tmp[i][j] = (char)0x41;
        }
    }
}
```

Every time you want to access `globalScreen` as a 2D array, you must cast it.

Otherwise, you may define it as an array in the beginning and you don't need the memory allocation at all.